# Removing unwanted text from file - Regular expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, file, regex-negation

I have a file that contains data to be processed. The file has all lines starting with 3 alphabets in small case , followed by underscore , like below

```
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
```

However, there are few instances where the previous line has overflown into next line like

```
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
belong to previous line
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
xvz_abcd  some data something ....
```

Is there any Regular expression i can use to find and replace such instances? Had similar issue earlier where i had to isolate lines NOT starting with 5 numerals. Used

```
\n{(^~(:z^5).*$)}
```

can i tweak this for my current problem?

P.S: I am trying this on visual studio IDE

Answer (score 1):

Try `[a-z]{3}_[a-z]{4} .*` to match the desired line in the file.